# Task queues with Flask - "module 'os' has no attribute 'fork'"

Tags: python, flask

**Introduction**

So, I'm trying to learn more about Flask, and I've been following this guide from Pythonise.com series. The website is no longer up, but I can still access it through Wayback machine. Here is the link to guide which I'm currently working with:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210410211818/https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/flask-rq-task-queue

I'm using Windows, so I had to install Redis on a Linux subsystem. I've used Ubuntu for this. My code editor is VScode. I get a `module 'os' has no attribute 'fork'` error when I try to add a new task to the queue.

**Error details**

Anyway, when I run the `rq worker` command in my terminal, I get this (which looks correct):

```
01:21:13 Worker rq:worker:e78a93050f0f400f9f2e75ce25fb2f63: started, version 1.10.1
01:21:13 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:e78a93050f0f400f9f2e75ce25fb2f63
01:21:13 *** Listening on ←[32mdefault←[39;49;00m...
```

I then run the `flask run` command in a second terminal, and then visits `http://127.0.0.1:5000/task?n=100` in my browser. The browser returns `Task (fad0b6b8-63a7-4213-a02a-edd40e41b284) added to queue at 2022-06-08 23:27:16.294717` (which looks correct). However, I get this error in my first terminal:

```
$ rq worker
01:21:13 Worker rq:worker:e78a93050f0f400f9f2e75ce25fb2f63: started, version 1.10.1
01:21:13 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:e78a93050f0f400f9f2e75ce25fb2f63
01:21:13 *** Listening on ←[32mdefault←[39;49;00m...
01:27:16 ←[32mdefault←[39;49;00m: ←[34mapp.test.background_task('100')←[39;49;00m (fad0b6b8-63a7-4213-a02a-edd40e41b284)
01:27:16 ←[31mWorker rq:worker:e78a93050f0f400f9f2e75ce25fb2f63: found an unhandled exception, quitting...←[39;49;00m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test_app\env\lib\site-packages\rq\worker.py", line 606, in work
    self.execute_job(job, queue)
  File "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test_app\env\lib\site-packages\rq\worker.py", line 866, in execute_job
    self.fork_work_horse(job, queue)
  File "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test_app\env\lib\site-packages\rq\worker.py", line 770, in fork_work_horse
    child_pid = os.fork()
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'fork'
01:27:16 Unsubscribing from channel rq:pubsub:e78a93050f0f400f9f2e75ce25fb2f63
```

**Folder structure and files**

```
test_app/
          app/
                __init__.py
                test.py
          run.py
          env/
```

**run.py**

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from app import test
```

**test.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from app import app
import redis
from rq import Queue
import time

r = redis.Redis()
q = Queue(connection=r)

def background_task(n):

    """ Function that returns len(n) and simulates a delay """

    delay = 2

    print("Task running")
    print(f"Simulating a {delay} second delay")

    time.sleep(delay)

    print(len(n))
    print("Task complete")

    return len(n)

@app.route("/task")
def index():

    if request.args.get("n"):

        job = q.enqueue(background_task, request.args.get("n"))

        return f"Task ({job.id}) added to queue at {job.enqueued_at}"

    return "No value for count provided"
```

Comment: the tutorial is intended for linux (or posixlike) -- windows doesn't have `fork`

Comment: Your "first terminal" is still running in Windows, not in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

os.fork() just run in unix systems! not in windows!